# Custom Post Type issue: amp doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm having trouble (again) with a Custom Post Type created on my Wordpress blog. 
It is mainly working: I can create a custom post ("articles") and set a city (taxonomy) to it and it gives me the url I'm wishing to read this page:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/city/title_of_the_article/
```

However, it seems that it's not responding well to some functionalities or plug-ins. Among them, AMP for WP - Accelerated Mobile Pages.

My AMP is working well everywhere (pages, post, another CPT) except on this CPT "articles" recently created.

In the AMP plug-in settings, I made sure my “articles” is activated in the Custom Post Type support so it should be fine.

What I want:
to have my amp url for this CPT like:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/city/title_of_the_article/amp/
```

So even if everything seems to be activated, I have a 404 error when I add /amp/ at the end these pages.

What is strange is that it is working when I try to type `https://www.example.com/blog/city/title_of_article/?amp` with ?amp at the end, even though it should be /amp/ and that it works with /amp/ for the rest of the posts or pages.

I tried with two other similar plug-in and same issue. I also tried to deactivate all my plug-ins, only leaving AMP activated, but the issue is still there. So I guess it comes from the setting up of this CPT. Here is my code associated with that custom post type and the taxonomy:

```
register_post_type( 'article', 
array( 'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Articles', 
    'singular_name' => 'Article', 
    'all_items' => 'All article', 
    'add_new' => 'Add article', 
    'add_new_item' => 'Add article',
    'edit' => 'Edit article', 
    'edit_item' =>  'Edit article', 
    'new_item' => 'New article', 
    'view_item' => 'View article', 
    'search_items' => 'Search article', 
    'not_found' =>  'Nothing found in the Database.', 
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
), 

'description' => 'This is the example custom post type', 
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'menu_position' => 10, 
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', 
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'adresses', 'with_front' => true ), 
'has_archive' => 'articles', 
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),


'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' )));
```

and

```
function resource_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'city', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'snt' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'city', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'snt' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Add city', 'snt' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All city', 'snt' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent city', 'snt' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent city:', 'snt' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New city', 'snt' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New city', 'snt' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit city', 'snt' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update city', 'snt' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View city', 'snt' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'snt' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove city', 'snt' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'snt' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular city', 'snt' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search city', 'snt' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'snt' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No article', 'snt' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'snt' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'snt' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'city')
);
register_taxonomy( 'city', array( 'article' ), $args );} 
       add_action( 'init', 'resource_type', 0 );
```

and

```
<?php

function resources_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
   $rules = array();
   $terms = get_terms( array(
     'taxonomy' => 'city',
     'hide_empty' => false,
   ) );

   $post_type = 'article';
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $rules[ $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . 
      $post_type. '&resources_post_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

   }
   $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'resources_cpt_generating_rule');



function change_link( $permalink, $post ) {

if( $post->post_type == 'article' ) {
    $resource_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'city' );
    $term_slug = '';
    if( ! empty( $resource_terms ) ) {
        foreach ( $resource_terms as $term ) {
            if( $term->slug == 'featured' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=="en"){
      $permalink = get_home_url() . '/' . $term_slug . '/' . $post->post_name . '/' ;
    }else{
      $permalink = get_home_url() . $term_slug . '/' . $post->post_name . '/' ;
    }
}
return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link',"change_link",10,2);
```

What I want:
`https://www.example.com/blog/city/title_of_the_article/amp/` to be working instead of `https://www.example.com/blog/city/title_of_the_article/amp?`

Thanks for your kind help, I'm kind of lost here... :)

Comment: It's not the same issue, but it's about the same CPT, right. I was thinking that maybe in this code there is something preventing AMP to be used.

Comment: In my opinion, you can add to previous question the solution you found and mention that it does not fully solve your problem.

Comment: Try replace `$term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'` to `$term->slug . '/([^/]*)(/amp/?)?$'`. `$` means  end of the subject, so only addresses that have nothing after the name of the post will match your rule.

Comment: Hello nmr, thank you for help. Yes I will add the question to the similar topic, makes more sense. In addition, I tried your solution, and the impact is that my page is working using /amp/ at the end of the url -  but it doesnt go the AMP version of the page (lighter version). It just goes to the classic version but with a modified url.